# Grails GORM order as a closure

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to use a closure as an order by clause as in:

```
def actionsByUser = UserAction.createCriteria().list(max:max, offset:offset) {
                    order(
                        {a,b -> "${a.id}${a.userCount}" <=> "${b.id}${b.userCount}"}
                    )
                }
```

I know that it may not make any sense in this case, but I have a use case where using a closure would be most helpful.

Comment: No it's not possible with GORM/Hibernate. However, you can run the query then do the sorting on the resulting collection using a closure and `.sort`.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I need to paginate the results as well. So, I'm looking into the PagedResultList after I've sorted the list. Using the range capability of the list.